# KO Carousel example does not work

Tags: knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm want to create a carousel component in Knockout.js I forked a knockout carousel example from jsfiddle.net. Here is the source code for it:

html:

```
<!-- start main slider carousel -->
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
                <!-- main slider carousel items -->
                <!-- ko foreach:imagePaths -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div data-bind='attr:{"data-slide-number": $index, "class": "item" }, css: {"active": $index() == 0}'>
                        <img data-bind='attr:{src: link, height: 200, width: 132, "class": "img-responsive", alt: alt }' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- main slider carousel nav controls -->
                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
<!-- end main slider carousel-->
<!-- start thumb navigation carousel -->
<div class="col-md-6 offset-top_1" id="slider-thumbs">

    <!-- thumb navigation carousel items -->
    <ol class="list-inline">
        <!-- ko foreach:imagePaths -->
        <li data-bind="attr: { 'data-slide-to': $index }">
            <a data-bind='attr:{"id": "carousel-selector-"+ $index() }'>
                <img data-bind="attr:{src: link, height: 20, width: 12, alt: alt }" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ol>

</div>
<!-- end thumb navigation carousel -->
```

javascript:

```
    var Image = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.alt = data.alt;
    self.link = data.link;
    self.title = data.title;
    self.active = data.active;
};

var CarouselViewModel = function (params) {

    var self = this;

    self.selectedImageIndex = ko.observable(params && params.selectedImageIndex || 0);
    self.imagePaths = ko.observableArray(params && params.imagePaths || []);
    self.addImage = function(img) {
        self.imagePaths.push(img);
    };

}

var viewModel = new CarouselViewModel({selectedImageIndex: 0, imagePaths: [] });
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.addImage({
alt: 'yellowstone-77', 
link: 'https://pshabalin.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/yellowstone-77.png', 
title: 'yellowstone-77'});

    viewModel.addImage({
    alt: 'yellowstone-77', 
    link: 'https://pshabalin.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/yellowstone-58.png', 
    title: 'yellowstone-58'});

    viewModel.addImage({
    alt: 'yellowstone-77', 
    link: 'https://pshabalin.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/img_1082.png', 
    title: 'img_1082.png'});

    viewModel.addImage(
    {alt: 'yellowstone-77', 
    link: 'https://pshabalin.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/dscn2295.png', 
    title: 'dscn2295'});
```

[jsfiddle.net reference](https://jsfiddle.net/tatjana69/0L9vb3m4/)

but i can not get it to work properly. Can anybody help me fix this.

Comment: What is the outcome of running the code? Please include the result or error.

Comment: @nateyolles there is no error but it doesn't work as expected. For see the outcome of running the code follow the jsfiddle reference link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 1st `<!-- ko foreach:imagePaths -->` is wrong positioned. It should be inside the `<div class="carousel-inner">` and not containing it.

Check the carousel working in the following fixed jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/elbecita/0L9vb3m4/58/

Comment: Yes this works but the images goes reverse, when you click left the images goes to right and when you click right the images goes left.

Comment: But that is a carousel way of working (in the jsfiddle you provided you loaded bootstrap, and that is how it works). You can check another example very similar behaving the same way here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Comment: I'm glad I've helped you! ^^

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @elbecita is correct. I pimped it a little up.

```
.carousel-active-thumb {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.carousel-thumb {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.carousel-thumbnail-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel-thumbnail-center ol {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  /* For IE */
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  height: 350px;
  width: auto;
}

.carousel-active-thumb a img {
  height: 41px;
  width: auto;
}

.carousel-thumb a img {
  height: 41px;
  width: auto;
}
```

Here is the fiddle therefor:

[bootstrap carousel in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/astrapi69/hu1fcmq2/)

I hope this can help anybody.